# 2D Convolution of complex vector with real vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, convolution, complex-numbers

I have a complex vector (type double) and another vector (type double), which I would like to perform 2D convolution with. Most of the examples I've seen online are not for complex vectors, so I'm not sure how to go about implementing it.

These are my vectors:

```
vector<complex<double> > signal;  // length of 100
vector<double> filter;            // length of 101
```

my 'signal' vector looks like this...

```
25 + 0.0000i, -9.04508 + 18.3273i, -3.45492 - 8.388i... and so on
```

my 'filter' vector looks like this...

```
0, 2.56698e-09, 9.13094e-09, 1.14301e-08... and so on
```

Ideally I'd like to output in to a complex vector, type double and to be the same length as 'signal'
So my output is:

```
vector<complex<double> > filtered_signal;
```

I'm still relatively inexperienced with C++ so any high-level tips/guidance on how to perform the calculation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

convolution formula can be found at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html

as you can see,

> w(k)= sum_j(  u(j)v(k−j+1) )

where sum with index j is in the range that keeps the indices valid on the two vectors.
k is between 0 and  m+n-1, where m = length(u) and n = length(v)

so if u(j) is complex and v(k) is real, the product is well defined.

```
std::vector<complex<double> > conv(const std::vector<complex<double> > &a, const std::vector<double> &b)
{
    std::vector<complex<double> > r(a.size()+b.size()-1);
    for (unsigned long i=0; i<r.size(); i++) {
        r[i] = 0;
        unsigned long s =(i+2-b.size()>0) ? i+2-b.size() : 0;
        for (unsigned long j=s ; j<min(a.size(),i+2) ; j++) {
            r[i] += a[j] * b[i-j+1];
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. But this is for the full convolution case, I'd like to output for the same size as my input signal.

Comment: also, this is for 1D convolution, in my case because I have complex vector with real and imaginary parts, i'd assume I need 2D convolution?

Comment: @Alex sorry but i don't get what you mean by 2D correlation. My answer was targeted to your original unedited question. Do you have any math reference? as per https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html 2d correlation is between matrices. So if you have vectors, that doesn't apply.

Comment: apologies, I was confused whether I needed correlation or convolution. I can confirm I need 2D convolution as described by https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html?s_tid=doc_ta

Comment: but because I have complex vector, this is split (real,imag)

Comment: On the link you posted there's the formula for the 2D convolution, it will be easy to implement as I did for 1D. I'm still doubtful you need 2D convolution though, my sixth sense tells me doesn't make much sense with your input.

Comment: The problem I'm having is I'd like to do 'same size' convolution and 1D doesn't do that. I have a signal of length 101 and a filter of length 101. I'd like my convolution output to be length 101, but 1D gives me a length of 201: `size(signal)+size(filter)-1`. Simply changing the length of the output vector in initialisation doesn't give me the correct values

Comment: You should probably look into the `shape` parameter in the link i put of the mathworks website, see where it says 'same' 
Central part of the convolution of the same size as u.? how do you think that is implemented?

Comment: Could I pad the signal vector by the `[size(signal)+1]/2`, so 51 in this case?

Comment: I think the correct name for the operation you want to do is "trim"